# Why can't I see the database updates unless I refresh the page?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

Hmmmmm I worked on some PHP code that pulls stock levels from my supplier and inserts the stock level into the database based on the product's SKU. I've inserted it into the class.product.php file which contains all the code used for the individual product page.  The issue I'm having is that when the product page loads, it doesn't show the updated inventory levels unless you hit refresh. I've moved the code all over the place and can't get it to update the database and have the updated number loaded before the page is displayed.

Even when placed before all other code, I still have to refresh the page to see the update. I don't know what else to do about this. I feel like perhaps, I don't truly understand how PHP loads code. I've been working on this every day for weeks. I tried running it as an include file, on a separate page, at the top, in the middle, all over the place.

In the class file, it looks like I have the code before it calls the code to display the stock levels, that's why I'm so confused as to why it won't load the updates.

Any thoughts on why I'm unable to see the changes unless I refresh the page?

Thanks!

Comment: The only issue i could think of is Caching. Specifically IE.

Comment: We're going to need to see some code to really help.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post some code now, I was thinking I'd get something like Aviatrix mentioned about how PHP accesses content.  :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP loads the content when you request it , 
so opening a page gets the content ONCE,

The thing you want to do to get data updated is have AJAX calls to a php function that return data in JSON or XML format 
Here you can see some [examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) but consider googling around for more detailed examples.

Comment: Thanks!  I've fixed it. I'll post an answer to my question. Thanks for the info. Not knowing that it only processes the code once is why I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my code was not running until after the code to get and display the product data because I was using info from the product data that was only being called once. So the product data had be be called first in order for my code to run. So to fix this, I had to create a new function that would get the sku and pass it to my code before the code that called the product data to be displayed on the page. I copied the existing function to get the product data, renamed it to GetRealTimeStockLevels and added my code to the bottom of it. I put the call for the function above the call for the product data and it worked like I wanted. I'm glad I got this worked out, now I can add the same feature to the checkout page.

Below is the function call at the start of the page and then the function I created to run my update code.

```
    public function __construct($productid=0)
    {
        // Get the stock level from supplier and update the database
        $this->_GetRealtimeStockLevels($productid);

        // Load the data for this product
        $this->_SetProductData($productid);

    public function _GetRealtimeStockLevels($productid=0)
    {

        if ($productid == 0) {
            // Retrieve the query string variables. Can't use the $_GET array
            // because of SEO friendly links in the URL
            SetPGQVariablesManually();
            if (isset($_REQUEST['product'])) {
                $product = $_REQUEST['product'];
            }
            else if(isset($GLOBALS['PathInfo'][1])) {
                $product = preg_replace('#\.html$#i', '', $GLOBALS['PathInfo'][1]);
            }
            else {
                $product = '';
            }


            $product = $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->Quote(MakeURLNormal($product));
            $productSQL = sprintf("p.prodname='%s'", $product);
        }
        else {
            $productSQL = sprintf("p.productid='%s'", (int)$productid);

        }

        $query = "
            SELECT p.*, FLOOR(prodratingtotal/prodnumratings) AS prodavgrating, pi.*, ".GetProdCustomerGroupPriceSQL().",
            (SELECT COUNT(fieldid) FROM [|PREFIX|]product_customfields WHERE fieldprodid=p.productid) AS numcustomfields,
            (SELECT COUNT(reviewid) FROM [|PREFIX|]reviews WHERE revstatus='1' AND revproductid=p.productid AND revstatus='1') AS numreviews,
            (SELECT brandname FROM [|PREFIX|]brands WHERE brandid=p.prodbrandid) AS prodbrandname,
            (SELECT COUNT(imageid) FROM [|PREFIX|]product_images WHERE imageprodid=p.productid) AS numimages,
            (SELECT COUNT(discountid) FROM [|PREFIX|]product_discounts WHERE discountprodid=p.productid) AS numbulkdiscounts
            FROM [|PREFIX|]products p
            LEFT JOIN [|PREFIX|]product_images pi ON (pi.imageisthumb=1 AND p.productid=pi.imageprodid)
            WHERE ".$productSQL;

        if(!isset($_COOKIE['STORESUITE_CP_TOKEN'])) {
            // ISC-1073: don't check visibility if we are on control panel
            $query .= " AND p.prodvisible='1'";
        }

        $result = $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->Query($query);
        $row = $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->Fetch($result);

        if (!$row) {
            return;
        }

        $this->_product = $row;
        $this->_prodid = $row['productid'];
        $this->_prodname = $row['prodname'];
        $this->_prodsku = $row['prodcode'];


        $GLOBALS['CurrentProductLink'] = ProdLink($this->_prodname);


                   $server_url = "http://ms.com/fgy/webservices/index.php";

                   $request = xmlrpc_encode_request("catalog.getStockQuantity", array($this->_prodsku));
                   $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
                   'method' => "POST",
                   'header' => "Content-Type: text/xml",
                   'content' => $request
                    )));
                   $file = file_get_contents($server_url, false, $context);
                   $response = xmlrpc_decode($file);

                   $query = sprintf("UPDATE [|PREFIX|]products SET prodcurrentinv='$response' where prodcode='%s'",    $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->Quote($this->_prodsku)); 
                   $result = $GLOBALS['ISC_CLASS_DB']->Query($query);


    }
```